# Animate cover background from scale: 0.8 to scale: 1 - keep 100% width+height

Tags: css, animation, css-animations

How would I go about animating a cover background from: `scale(0.8)` to `scale(1)` while still keeping 100% width + height?

I've tried animating the transform property, however the natural result of that is what you can see in this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jwL0sdyy/) - with the background not filling out 100% in width + height when scaled 0.8.

I looking for the image to stay in 100% cover even when it's scaled down and not distort the image by a higher scale than 1

Answer (score 0):

Background-size: cover should do the trick, you combine it with transform zoom.

https://css-tricks.com/zooming-background-images/

Comment: That's basically what im doing now. In your example they're upscaling the image from scale: 1 to scale: 1.2 upon hover - whereas im trying to fulfill the same zoom technique, but just from 0.8 to 1 - my challenge is that I want the image to stay in 100% cover even when it's scaled down and not distort the image by a higher scale than 1

Answer (score 0):

The `<body></body` Tag has a default margin.

Add this snippet to your css and it should be gone:

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}
```